# 2D text drawing function have huge impact on performance

Tags: performance, opengl, text, shader

I am working on a small OpenGL-based game. It's quite simple so my event-loops are quite fast and I get a refresh rate of `~1200fps`.

However, I am now using some 2D text rendering function which map parts of a 2D texture to the screen. 
It's not my code, I am using this source: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-11-2d-text/

The problem with this code is that it has a huge impact on the performance. The refresh rate drops to about `800fps` which wouldn't really be a problem but I also noticed some spikes where a single event loop-pass take really long.

My normal passes take about `0.002` seconds, even when using `std::cout` in the event loop. The spikes, single frames, take from `0.05s` to nearly `0.1s`. The question is why I get these spikes with the text function but not without.

Some important facts: 
The function is called twice in every loop, with about 10 characters. The texture used for the characters is a 5mb `.dds` file, 2048² pixels.
The parts I am most concerned with are the OpenGL parts, switching the shader and so on. Do they have an heavy impact on the performance?

The shaders are not worth mentioning. My in-game shader uses a fixed color for a wireframe look and the texture shader only calculates where to sample at in the texture.
Do you have an idea what could cause this trouble?

**INIT FUNCTION**

```cpp
void initText2D(const char * texturePath){

    // Initialize texture
    Text2DTextureID = loadDDS(texturePath);

    // Initialize VBO
    glGenBuffers(1, &Text2DVertexBufferID);
    glGenBuffers(1, &Text2DUVBufferID);

    // Initialize Shader
    Text2DShaderID = LoadShaders( "TextVertexShader.vertexshader", "TextVertexShader.fragmentshader" );

    // Initialize uniforms' IDs
    Text2DUniformID = glGetUniformLocation( Text2DShaderID, "myTextureSampler" );
}
```

**DRAW FUNCTION**

```cpp
void printText2D(const char * text, int x, int y, int size, int widthOffset){

    unsigned int length = strlen(text);

    // Fill buffers
    std::vector<glm::vec2> vertices;
    std::vector<glm::vec2> UVs;
    for ( unsigned int i=0 ; i<length ; i++ ){

        glm::vec2 vertex_up_left    = glm::vec2( x+i*(size+widthOffset)    , y+size );
        glm::vec2 vertex_up_right   = glm::vec2( x+i*(size+widthOffset)+size, y+size );
        glm::vec2 vertex_down_right = glm::vec2( x+i*(size+widthOffset)+size, y      );
        glm::vec2 vertex_down_left  = glm::vec2( x+i*(size+widthOffset)     , y      );

        vertices.push_back(vertex_up_left   );
        vertices.push_back(vertex_down_left );
        vertices.push_back(vertex_up_right  );

        vertices.push_back(vertex_down_right);
        vertices.push_back(vertex_up_right);
        vertices.push_back(vertex_down_left);

        char character = text[i];
        float uv_x = (character%16)/16.0f;
        float uv_y = (character/16)/16.0f;

        glm::vec2 uv_up_left    = glm::vec2( uv_x           , uv_y );
        glm::vec2 uv_up_right   = glm::vec2( uv_x+1.0f/16.0f, uv_y );
        glm::vec2 uv_down_right = glm::vec2( uv_x+1.0f/16.0f, (uv_y + 1.0f/16.0f) );
        glm::vec2 uv_down_left  = glm::vec2( uv_x           , (uv_y + 1.0f/16.0f) );
        UVs.push_back(uv_up_left   );
        UVs.push_back(uv_down_left );
        UVs.push_back(uv_up_right  );

        UVs.push_back(uv_down_right);
        UVs.push_back(uv_up_right);
        UVs.push_back(uv_down_left);
    }

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DVertexBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DUVBufferID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, UVs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &UVs[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // Bind shader
    glUseProgram(Text2DShaderID);

    // Bind texture
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Text2DTextureID);
    // Set our "myTextureSampler" sampler to user Texture Unit 0
    glUniform1i(Text2DUniformID, 0);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DVertexBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );

    // 2nd attribute buffer : UVs
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DUVBufferID);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0 );
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    // Draw call
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size() );

    //glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

}
```

Comment: My initial thought is that the drop from 1200 to 800 fps might not be that big, if you weren't doing much to begin with. I wouldn't worry about optimizing stuff before you actually need to, and 800 fps doesn't seem call for a need-to-basis. Other than that, you can always consider doing instanced rendering.

Comment: The bigger problems are the annoying spike of 0.05 - 0.1 seconds. They are realy noticable and also not rare. But you are right, 800fps isn't realy a big deal with this simple render-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code that might be affecting the performance.

**1)** Using `std::vector` inside a function that is called in a tight loop:

```
std::vector<glm::vec2> vertices;
std::vector<glm::vec2> UVs;
```

`std::vector` is a growable array, but growing it usually has an elevated cost (a new memory allocation and a copy, more than likely). Your are doing a lot of `push_back`s inside that loop, god knows how many times the vectors will reallocate-copy its contents to accommodate the new data.

Solutions: Use a statically allocated array, which is the most efficient way, but limits the number of chars that can be printed per call, or, reserve memory beforehand with the [`reserve()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/) method:

```
// 3 vertes for each triangle in the quad 
const size_t numVerts = 6;
cosnt size_t numUVs   = 6;

vertices.reserve(length * numVerts);
UVs.reserve(length * numUVs);

for ( unsigned int i=0 ; i<length ; i++ )
{
    // all the rest ...
}
```

**2)** Some unnecessary GL state change:

```
glUniform1i(Text2DUniformID, 0);
```

Can be called once in the init function, since it never changes.

```
void initText2D(const char * texturePath)
{
    ...
    glUseProgram(Text2DShaderID);
    glUniform1i(Text2DUniformID, 0);
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

There seem to be some other unnecessary state changes in the draw function, such as:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Unless you are changing that somewhere else, there is no need to call it every draw.

**3)** `GL_STREAM_DRAW` and VAOs:

You are specifying the buffer data with `GL_STATIC_DRAW`. This is wrong for a buffer that is updated so frequently. The best flag would be `GL_STREAM_DRAW`. See the documentation of [`glBufferData()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBufferData.xml) for more info.

Also, consider using a [Vertex Array Object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). This should also optimize your rendering.

**4)** Consider batching your rendering calls:

The main performance bottleneck here is clearly the fact that each `printText2D` call is updating a GL buffer and performing a draw call. With a bit of effort you can batch all these print calls into some data structure of your choice and submit all buffer updates and draw calls at once. Make `printText2D` write to a CPU-side buffer and then at a latter time, perhaps at the end of the normal 3D rendering, flush that buffer to OpenGL in one go. This is likely to impact performance the most.

Comment: Hi, 

thanks for all the tipps. :) 
1) I will adjust the code so the vector reservs the necessary place.

2) Does the Program (shader) store these values? after I printed the text, I switch to another shader-program. I thought that this will discard these values.

I don't use glBlend in my other shader-program. Does this value "remember" the program?

3) Thanks! :)

4) Do you have an idea, what this could look like?

Again, thanks for all the tipps.!

Comment: Btw: My HUD displays timers and stuff so the strings used change very frequenlty.

Comment: The shader uniforms only have to be updated if the previous value changes. Unbinding the shader program does not thrash the uniform var values. Any GL state that you set will remain set until changed. So if you enable blend, it will remain enabled until the next call to disable it. The GL states are not related to the shader programs.

Comment: Good to know. I thought that at least the uniforms don't remain set. But other than uniforms, something like glBlend is shared  by other shaders so you have to know, if blend is necessary for the shader or not, right?

Comment: Sure, blending is a global state, so if the shader necessitates blending, you will have to manually enable it. The shader programs cannot modify any global state by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the lag spikes! (However I still don't know why they where there in the first place)

Instead of using `glBufferData();` every frame, I now use `glBufferSubData` which only updates the buffer but doesn't reallocate it.

So the file now looks like this:

**HEADER (part)**

```cpp
int maxSize = 20;
// Initialize VBO
glGenBuffers(1, &Text2DVertexBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DVertexBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*maxSize * sizeof(glm::vec2), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);

glGenBuffers(1, &Text2DUVBufferID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DUVBufferID);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6*maxSize * sizeof(glm::vec2), NULL, GL_STREAM_DRAW);
```

**RENDER FUNCTION (part)**

```cpp
// update buffer data
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DVertexBufferID);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &vertices[0]);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Text2DUVBufferID);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, UVs.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2), &UVs[0]);
```

Important to keep in mind is that you have to either limit the string to fit in the max buffer size or to reallocate the buffer only if needed.
A good idea would be to write a class for a single label which can keep stuff like this in mind but for now, this will do. :)

Thanks for all the performance-tips, they also have an effect.